# how to styled st.expander in streamlit and python

Tags: python, css, if-statement, streamlit

having a dataframe that i want to display its result using `st.expander`  widget  based on the value of column **type** i want to styled the header of the expander.

## code:

```
   cols = st.columns(len(df))
            
    for i ,x in enumerate(cols):
    
    if df[i]['type'] == 'employee':
                   
                    font_css ='''
                        <style>
                            .streamlit-expanderHeader.st-ae.st-dj.st-ag.st-ah.st-ai.st-aj.st-bv.st-dk.st-bw.st-dl.st-dm.st-dn.st-do.st-ar.st-as.st-dp.st-dq.st-b3.st-cj.st-c5.st-dr.st-b4.st-ds.st-c3.st-c4.st-c2.st-c1{
                               font-size:30px;
                               text-align:center;     
                               color:yellow;
                               background-color :red;
                        }
                        </style>
                        
                    '''
                    st.write(font_css,unsafe_allow_html = True)
    
                if df[i]['type'] == 'supervisor':
                  
                    font_css ='''
                        <style>
                            .streamlit-expanderHeader.st-ae.st-dj.st-ag.st-ah.st-ai.st-aj.st-bv.st-dk.st-bw.st-dl.st-dm.st-dn.st-do.st-ar.st-as.st-dp.st-dq.st-b3.st-cj.st-c5.st-dr.st-b4.st-ds.st-c3.st-c4.st-c2.st-c1{
                               font-size:30px;
                               text-align:center;     
                               color:Green;
                        }
                        </style>
                        
                    '''
                    st.write(font_css,unsafe_allow_html = True)
                if df[i]['type'] == 'CEO':
                   
                    font_css ='''
                        <style>
                            .streamlit-expanderHeader.st-ae.st-dj.st-ag.st-ah.st-ai.st-aj.st-bv.st-dk.st-bw.st-dl.st-dm.st-dn.st-do.st-ar.st-as.st-dp.st-dq.st-b3.st-cj.st-c5.st-dr.st-b4.st-ds.st-c3.st-c4.st-c2.st-c1{
                               font-size:30px;
                               text-align:center;     
                               color:blue;
                               background-color :red;
                        }
                        </style>
                        
                    '''
                    st.write(font_css,unsafe_allow_html = True)
                
                
    
                with st.expander(f"{df[i]['name']}"):
                    
                
                    st.image(df[i][f'ImgPath'],width=100)
```

using the code above it doesn't display the correct result where all the selected record will be displayed with the same style even if the df['type'] is different
so how to fix this code